# LWC: Delete all dates if first date deleted

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-data-service

Method 'delete all dates of previous date deleted' is not working.
When i refresh page all dates on the same place except first date - it's deleted.

> **IF YOU DON'T WANT TO ANSWER, PLEASE SEND REASON IN COMMENTS. IS IT STUPID QUESTION OR DIFFICULT QUESTION?**

[image]

**JS**

```
 @track tripId;
 @track trip;

 @track ticket_date1;
 @track ticket_date2;
 @track ticket_date3;
 @track ticket_date4;

 // ------------- CONNECTED CALLBACK -----------
 @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;
 connectedCallback() {
     registerListener('sendTripId', this.handleSendTripId, this);
     this.resetVars();
 }
 resetVars() {

     this.ticket_date1 = '';
     this.ticket_date2 = '';
     this.ticket_date3 = '';
     this.ticket_date4 = '';

 }
 // -------- GET TRIP ID FROM LIST ----------
 handleSendTripId(tripId) {
     if (tripId === null) {
         this.trip = undefined;
         this.tripId = undefined;
         return;
     }
     this.tripId = tripId;
 }
 // ---------- GET TRIP BY ID ------------------
 @wire(getTrip, {
     recordId: '$tripId'
 })
 wiredGetActivityHistory({
     data
 }) {
     if (data) {
         this.trip = data;
         this.ticket_date1 = this.trip.RUEV_Trip_Ticket_Date_1__c === undefined ? undefined : this.trip.RUEV_Trip_Ticket_Date_1__c;
         this.ticket_date2 = this.trip.RUEV_Trip_Ticket_Date_2__c === undefined ? undefined : this.trip.RUEV_Trip_Ticket_Date_2__c;
         this.ticket_date3 = this.trip.RUEV_Trip_Ticket_Date_3__c === undefined ? undefined : this.trip.RUEV_Trip_Ticket_Date_3__c;
         this.ticket_date4 = this.trip.RUEV_Trip_Ticket_Date_4__c === undefined ? undefined : this.trip.RUEV_Trip_Ticket_Date_4__c;

     }
 }

 // ----------------FIELD CHANGES -------
 handleChange(event) {
     const targetName = event.target.dataset.name;
     if (targetName === 'ticket_date1') {
         this.ticket_date1 = event.target.value;
         if (event.target.value === null || event.target.value === '') {
             this.ticket_date2 = '';
             this.ticket_date3 = '';
             this.ticket_date4 = '';
         }
     } else if (targetName === 'ticket_date2') {
         this.ticket_date2 = event.target.value;
         if (event.target.value === null || event.target.value === '') {
             this.ticket_date3 = null;
             this.ticket_date4 = null;
         }
     } else if (targetName === 'ticket_date3') {
         this.ticket_date3 = event.target.value;
         if (event.target.value === null || event.target.value === '') {
             this.ticket_date4 = null;

         }
     } else if (targetName === 'ticket_date4') {
         this.ticket_date4 = event.target.value;
     }
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<template if:true={trip}>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="RUEV_Trip__c" record-id={tripId} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
        <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>

        Tickets: {ticket_date1} / {ticket_date2} / {ticket_date3} / {ticket_date4}

        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_1-of-4">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="RUEV_Trip_Ticket_Date_1__c" value={ticket_date1}
                    data-name="ticket_date1" onchange={handleChange}>
                </lightning-input-field>

            </div>
            <template if:true={ticket_date1}>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_1-of-4">
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="RUEV_Trip_Ticket_Date_2__c" value={ticket_date2}
                        data-name="ticket_date2" onchange={handleChange}>
                    </lightning-input-field>

                </div>
                <template if:true={ticket_date2}>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_1-of-4">
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="RUEV_Trip_Ticket_Date_3__c" value={ticket_date3}
                            data-name="ticket_date3" onchange={handleChange}>
                        </lightning-input-field>

                    </div>
                    <template if:true={ticket_date3}>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_1-of-4">
                            <lightning-input-field field-name="RUEV_Trip_Ticket_Date_4__c" value={ticket_date4}
                                data-name="ticket_date4" onchange={handleChange}>
                            </lightning-input-field>

                        </div>
                    </template>
                </template>
            </template>
        </div>
   <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="success" type="submit" name="update"
                                    label="Update">
                                </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

Comment: did the record get saved when you clicked that button?

Comment: yes, first date is deleted, and others are not deleted.

Comment: so when you clicked that button record got saved with all four date as empty?

Comment: thank you for you reply. i need to clear all values. but only empty record is first, which value i deleted. but on front end it shows that all are empty. when i refresh page they are not empty.

Comment: can you also share the code for the button that you are pressing

Comment: added to html body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One week of suffering, and result is:
if you clear values of field in JS and make this empty field hidden - it doesn't save hidden field

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULGr4BOogvw